# While configuring tomcat to use only 1 thread, when using completablefuture for async processing, it is using another thread how?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, completable-future

I have an endpoint using CompletableFuture for async processing and I have configured embedded tomcat to have only one thread as below:

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=1
```

and my endpoint is as below:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/asyncCompletable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CompletableFuture<String> getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture() {
    log.info("Request received");
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
            = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::processRequest);
    log.info("Servlet thread released");
    return completableFuture;
}
```

When hitting endpoint several times(for example 3 times simultaneously) in browser, the console log is as below:

```
19:20:19.234 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] Request received 
19:20:19.234 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] Servlet thread released 
19:20:19.234 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0] Start processing request 
19:20:19.839 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] Request received 
19:20:19.859 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] Servlet thread released 
19:20:19.859 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Start processing request 
19:20:20.595 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] Request received 
19:20:20.596 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] Servlet thread released 
19:20:20.596 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] Start processing request 
19:20:24.235 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0] Completed processing request 
19:20:24.235 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0] Start reversing string 
19:20:24.235 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0] Completed reversing string 
19:20:24.860 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Completed processing request 
19:20:24.860 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Start reversing string 
19:20:24.860 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Completed reversing string 
19:20:25.596 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] Completed processing request 
19:20:25.597 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] Start reversing string
```

As you could see, since I have configured tomcat to have only 1 thread in its threadpool, so for all 3 request it is using **http-nio-9191-exec-1**, but since I am using CompletableFuture it is using different thread namely (**e.g. ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2**) to process async task.
From where it is using new thread? since I have only one thread available in tomcat threadpool.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [supplyAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) method documentation says:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() with the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.

The common pool is created by the JVM, it is described in the [ForkJoinPool API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html):

> A static commonPool() is available and appropriate for most applications. The common pool is used by any ForkJoinTask that is not explicitly submitted to a specified pool. Using the common pool normally reduces resource usage (its threads are slowly reclaimed during periods of non-use, and reinstated upon subsequent use).

Since this pool isn’t created by Tomcat the max thread limit doesn’t apply.